# Core-Plot: Initially axis labels not on major ticks

Tags: label, core-plot

Something peculiar is happening on my scatterplot graphs. When the graph loads initially, the labels of the x and y axes are shown between the major tick marks (actually a bit more toward one than the next) rather than offset and on the major tick marks.

Curiously, touching any of the objects on the view -- info button, slider, or text fields -- immediately corrects the problem and it remains solved as data are changed or added.

I have never seen this behavior before and am using code to set the labels and tick marks that has always worked before. I wonder if this is some quirk added when moving from CorePlot_0.4 to CorePlot_0.9 or moving from Xcode 4.2 to Xcode 5.

Lastly, I should mention that this odd behavior happens on the iPhone simulator and the iPhone 4, but not on my 1st generation iPad or the iPad simulator. Very, very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed recently. See the Core Plot [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=363) for details. Either pull the latest code using Mercurial or wait for the next release.